# Weierstrass transform of polynomial with negative fractional power

Tags: definite-integrals, laplace-transform, hypergeometric-function

My goal is to evaluate

$I = \int_{-\infty}^\infty (1+bx^2)^{-k/2} e^{-ax^2} dx$

where $a,b>0$ and $k\in\mathbb{N}$. My first thought was to use the fact that we are integrating an even function on a symmetric interval and then substitute $y=x^2$, giving

$I = \int_0^\infty y^{-1/2}(1+by)^{-k/2}e^{-ay}dy$

Mathematica tells me that this evaluates to

$I=\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{1-k}{2}\right) \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^{-\frac{k}{2}} ~ _1F_1\left(\frac{k}{2};\frac{k+1}{2};\frac{a}{b}\right)}{\sqrt{a}}+\frac{\sqrt{\pi } \Gamma \left(\frac{k-1}{2}\right)  ~_1F_1\left(\frac{1}{2};\frac{3-k}{2};\frac{a}{b}\right)}{\sqrt{b} \Gamma \left(\frac{k}{2}\right)}$

But I haven't been able to figure out what this follows from. Identity 16.5.3 from [here](https://dlmf.nist.gov/16.5) can be used to find a solution in terms of$~_2F_0$, but I would prefer to not have a result involving an asymptotic series.

Are there any known results that would help me to understand the computer calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any future readers, this is actually pretty straightforward. The integral

$=\int_0^\infty y^{-1/2}(1+by)^{-k/2}e^{-ay}dy$

is known to be an integral representation of the Tricomi confluent hypergeometric function (see 13.4.4 [here](https://dlmf.nist.gov/13.4)).

Then we can use the fact that

$U(a,b,z) = \frac{\Gamma(1-b)}{\Gamma(a+1-b)}~_1F_1(a,b,z) + \frac{\Gamma(b-1)}{\Gamma(a)}z^{1-b}~_1F_1(a+1-b,2-b,z)$

to get the desired result.